# NodeJs C API vs. Using Unix Sockets

Tags: node.js

I have a C library and a C-based server and am trying to interact with my Node.js server. The two will always be on the same machine. I have two options to send the data from the C-server to the Node server or have interaction between the two: One using UNIX sockets and another using Node.js N-API. Which would be better choice?